# How to suspend and resume scope.$$watchers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I create complex form in angularjs 1.4. And I need use modal dialog but watchers from main form affect badly to performance.
I use next method for disable watchers:

```
.directive('suspendable', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    link: function (scope) {
        // Heads up: this might break is suspend/resume called out of order
        // or if watchers are added while suspended
        var watchers;
        var depth = 0;
        scope.$on('suspend', function (event, args) {
            if(watchers){
                return;
            }
            depth = args.depth;
            watchers = scope.$$watchers;
            scope.$$watchers = [];              
            console.log(depth + ' suspend ' + (watchers?watchers.length:0));
        });

        scope.$on('resume', function (event, args) {
            if (watchers && (depth == args.depth)) {
                scope.$$watchers = watchers;
                scope.$$watchersCount = watchers.length;
                watchers = void 0;                  
                console.log(depth + ' resume ' + (watchers.length));
            }
        });
    }
};}])
```

I add `suspendable` directive to all my directives in main form and I call broadcast event `suspend` before show modal dialog and call broadcast event `resume` after dialog close. But I haven't got watchers functionality after resume.

Comment: Can't imagine watcher perform that badly. That seems more like an architecture problem.

Comment: That remember me asking the exact same question more than one year from now for this exact usecase. Was left unanswered. Still no clean approach to disable watchers from a scope tree. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/MeH87xbZvUI

Comment: But I follow @Sulthan here. Now, specially with one-time bindings, There would be no reason for this kind of needs. What I did at this time was simply to $destroy() the scope of the page underneath the popin, and to force route reload when closing the popin. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `resume`:

```
scope.$on('resume', function (event, args) {
            if (watchers && (depth == args.depth)) {
                if (!scope.$$watchers ) {
                    scope.$$watchers = watchers;
                } else {
                    scope.$$watchers = scope.$$watchers.concat(watchers);
                }
                console.log(depth + ' resume ' + (watchers.length));
                watchers = void 0;
            }
        });
```

It helped me!

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS 1.7 has a new feature - the ability to suspend and resume scope watchers - 
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/41d5c90f170cc054b0f8f88220c22ef1ef6cc0a6

A call to `scope.$suspend()` will prevent watchers on this scope sub-tree from executing during digest.

Calling `scope.$resume()` will resume the watchers execution.